# Beamer and siunitx - overlay problem

Tags: beamer, siunitx, overlays

I try to make a table with `siunitx` column type in a beamer document with overlay. Here is a minimal non working example :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array,tikz}

\usepackage[%
    locale=FR,%
    detect-all,%
    table-number-alignment = center-decimal-marker,
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
    group-minimum-digits=4]{siunitx} % \num{} ...

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{S}
3.25 \\ \visible<2->{50.2337} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Produces this error message :

```
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
<recently read> }

l.20 \end{frame}
```

with the next correction :

```
\begin{tabular}{S}
3.25 \\ {\visible<2->{50.2337}} \\
\end{tabular}
```

No error message, but the result is not the one expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard `S` column can only deal with things which are 'really' numbers if you want alignment. However, `siunitx` also provides `\tablenum` to pad a number as it would in a table cell but in other contexts. For example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{S}
3.25 \\ \multicolumn{1}{c}{\visible<2->{\tablenum{50.2337}}} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(I've had to use `\multicolumn` here as a simple brace escape fails: that's an issue in `siunitx` but probably won't be fixed until I finalise version 3.)

Answer (score 1):

Why no use

```
\begin{tabular}{Sc}
3.25&\pause \\ 50.2337
\end{tabular}
```

? `siunitx` seems to have a conflict with *overlay specifications* of `beamer` inside a *table*.

Comment: I need `\sinuitx`, I don't need `tabular`. If there is a way to align the two numbers on the decimal comma without tabular...

Comment: @Tarass Your comment doesn't make sense, you use a `tabular` yourself. And you can answer your own question, so please do that, rather than adding your solution to the question.

Comment: When I said I don't need tabular, I meant I can avoid tabular but not `siunutx`. As there is a conflict between I wrote a fake. As you see, I need cuting numbers by slice of 3 , keeping useless zeros (that `siunitx` does and it's why I tried with it first), but `dcolum` doesn't, tried it before as an alternative (useless 0 desapear). One can use `lualatex` to fake `siunitx`, another possiblity could be `xstring`.